# SyntaxError with Sequelize, Identifier 'sequelize' has already been declared

Tags: sequelize.js

I am learning Sequelize and im following the teachers class, but im getting an error that he isn't getting. (maybe im wrong but i think im writing everything exactly as he is).

This is the file sequelize.js inside the folder libs:

```
const { sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const { config } = require('./../config/config');
const setupModels = require('./../db/models');


const USER = encodeURIComponent(config.dbUser);
const PASSWORD = encodeURIComponent(config.dbPassword);
const URI = `mysql://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${config.dbHost}:${config.dbPort}/${config.dbName}`;


const sequelize = new Sequelize(URI, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: true,
});

setupModels(sequelize);



module.exports = sequelize;
```

and this is the message im getting in the terminal when i run the project:

> [nodemon] restarting due to changes... [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> C:\Users\DanielaStornelli\Programacion\proyectos\my-store-data\libs\sequelize.js:12
> const sequelize = new Sequelize(URI, {
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: Identifier 'sequelize' has already been declared
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\DanielaStornelli\Programacion\proyectos\my-store-data\services\product.service.js:5:19)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
>
> Node.js v18.8.0 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes
> before starting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `Sequelize`, just change the first letter in the import statement:

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
```

Comment: thank you very much! i cannot believe this was my problem all along ‍♀️

Comment: Don't sweat it! Good luck!